# new line character creating issue in replacing key-value pair in python

Tags: python-3.x, character

**in a piece of code i need to replace the environment -
example :**

```
txt = "defaultValue":  "dev"
```

*Now i want to replace the value "dev" with "uat"*

*it is working fine until new line is introduced.*
**so**

```
"defaultValue":
```

`"dev"`

is not working. what will be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only the '\n' in the uat means we can remove it using this code.

```
txt = {"defaultValue": "dev"}
print("Initial:     ", txt)
new_val = "\nuat\n"
txt['defaultValue'] = new_val
print("after update:",txt)
txt["defaultValue"] = new_val.replace("\n", "")
print("Final:       ", txt)

# Output:
# Initial:      {'defaultValue': 'dev'}
# after update: {'defaultValue': '\nuat\n'}
# Final:        {'defaultValue': 'uat'}
```